Calling function wrapped in useCallback from useEffect updates state too many times
After coming back from Vue land I find myself suddenly back in React land and my usage of hooks so far haven't gotten passed the basic stages until today where I found myself trying to update multiple states when the depecendy mapped for useEffect changes
So basically my thought was to implement a Blackjack hook, for starters it will just be client side and that might be putting me into some problems I shouldn't face if I had the backend done. But I still want to learn what I can do to avoid this in the future my hook has these functions:
  const drawDealerCard = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("drawDealerCard");
    setDeck((prevDeck) => {
      const deckCopy = [...prevDeck];
      const newCard = deckCopy.pop();

      console.log("setDeck");
      setDealerHand((prevHand) => {
        console.log("setDealerHand");
        return [...prevHand, newCard!];
      });

      return deckCopy;
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDealerHidden) {
      console.log("useEffect isDealerHidden changed");
      drawDealerCard();
    }
  }, [isDealerHidden, drawDealerCard]);

When isDealerHidden changes to false I want to call the drawDealerCard function. I put it outside because I have this useEffect that deals a new card when the dealer hasn't reached a high enough score
    if (!isDealerHidden && dealerHand.length >= 2) {
      const dealerScore = calculateScore(dealerHand as PlayingCard[]);
      console.log("Dealer hand", dealerHand);
      console.log("Dealer score", dealerScore);
      setDealerScore(dealerScore);

      if (parseInt(dealerScore) < 17) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          //drawDealerCard();
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  }, [dealerHand, isDealerHidden, drawDealerCard]);

I have not come to any errors with this yet.
But my problem is from the first code that the "setDeck" state update is running twice, as i get double the console output and the setDealerHand in turn is logged 4 times. How do I avoid this as this would give the "Dealer" 3 cards with the new card duplicated and not the expected 2.

Don't worry about double execution when being in development mode with React, my guess: Strict Mode with a development build. Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode.
Why did you set the const function drawDealerCard as a dependecy for your useEffect hook? This hook triggers upon changes of the provided dependencies, hence it gets called upon changes of isDealerHidden and drawDealerCard. I reckon to only keep isDealerHidden.

This is another problem I've been dealing with that I don't understand because if I don't put drawDealerCard in the dependency array  I will get a message from ESLint about missing dependency eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) I don't know whats best turning off the warning entirely feels wrong, turning it off just for this useEffect looks kinda bad in the code.

You definitely don't want to add variables to the dependency array just for the sake of removing that warning @indiehjaerta ! Once you made a decision which variable to listen to/hook into, then you add it to the dependency array... and if ESLint complains, suppress the warning with that "magic" comment (you'll get used to it, it's less problematic than dealing with undesired side effects).

Thank you, I'll guess I just have to do that.
